# Css float drawbacks

Tags: css, css-float

Here goes the code:

```
 <style>
   .thumbnail
   {
   float:left;
   width:110px;
   height:90px;
   margin:5px;
  }
</style>
  <body>
  <img src="klematis_small.jpg" style="width:107px; height:140px">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="klematis_small.jpg" style="width:107px; height:150px">
```

The confusing is why the second img which is floated appering before the first img.If we place the first img to second img everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Floated elements are taken out of the [normal document flow:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow)

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box of the float.

Only line boxes (elements in the inline formatting context) respect floats, usually this is in the form of text. Also remember that floats will always be positioned on *top* (in the stacking order) when colliding with in-flow block level elements, but it will appear *behind* all lines boxes ..

> The contents of floats are stacked as if floats generated new stacking contexts, except that any positioned elements and elements that actually create new stacking contexts take part in the float's parent stacking context. A float can overlap other boxes in the normal flow (e.g., when a normal flow box next to a float has negative margins). When this happens, floats are rendered in front of non-positioned in-flow blocks, but behind in-flow inlines.

The section on floats in the [Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) is helpful if you're interested in learning the specifics

---

<sup>References: [Section 9.4, Floats, CSS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)</sup>

Comment: Could you pls explain with an example, _when colliding with in-flow block level elements, but it will appear behind all lines boxes .._ with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You copy example from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) but didn't read:

> How Elements Float
>   Elements are floated horizontally, this means that an element can only be floated left or right, not up or down.
>
> A floated element will move as far to the left or right as it can.
>   Usually this means all the way to the left or right of the containing
>   element.

Comment: does this mean it will take the position of any other element

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is normal and expected. If you want the first one first, you need to float them both.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt use floats, just use display: inline-block; which will display your items exactly in the same order as the code is written.